# Form Data from a client is not reaching the server

Tags: angular, http, vert.x

I am performing a POST operation to a Vert.x web server. I am having difficulty getting the POST data to the server.

I am performing the POST using an Angular client. The client code is below:

```
addUser(theCaller: Observer, nwUser: UserInfo): void {
    const thedata: FormData = new FormData();
    const data = JSON.stringify(nwUser);
    thedata.append('uInfo', data);

    const result: Observable<WebResult> = this.httpReq.post<WebResult>('http://localhost:8084/manage/add', thedata);
    result.subscribe({
      next: res => {
        if (res.goodOp === true) {
           console.info('User '+res.userName + 'created.');
        } 
      },
      error: err => {
        console.error('Add operation failed. ' + err);
      }
    });
  }
```

The vert.x server code for handling the POST request is below:

```
 theRouter.post(path).handler(actx->{
    HttpServerResponse resp = rCtx.response();
    resp.putHeader("content-type",ctxType);
    resp.setChunked(true);
    MultiMap map = theCtx.request().params();

     String str = map.get("uInfo");

     ...do other stuff with str...
 });
```

The problem occurs at the server. When str is set from the MultiMap map, it is always null. In fact, the entire MultiMap object that is supposed to contain the parameters contains a number of null values. For some reason, the form data I am sending from the client is not getting to the server.

I am clearly missing something, but I cannot see what it is. Am I doing something wrong at the client, or am I missing something from the server?

Can someone provide some insight into this? How can I get the form processed properly by the server?

EDIT: Prior to posting this question, I did experiment with Vert.x getting the body of my POST request in order to get the parameter I sent. Looking at the Vert.x documentation and some random examples I found elsewhere on the Internet, I figured I would have to get the JSON directly from the body. The Vert.x code to do this is below:

```
theRouter.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

theRouter.post(path).handler(actx->{
    HttpServerResponse resp = rCtx.response();
    resp.putHeader("content-type",ctxType);
    resp.setChunked(true);

    JsonObject json = actx.getBodyAsJson();
    logger.info("json object contains: "+json);

     ...do other stuff with json...
 });
```

The JsonObject called json is also a null. My parameter still appears to be not reaching the POST route.

Comment: Do you have smth like router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create()); in your code?
If no body handler added, your handlers will not get request data. See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_request_body_handling

Comment: Actually, Didar Burmaganov, I did look at body handling just before I started this Topic. The body handler I used returned a null, also. I will edit my question to include this information...

Comment: is it requirement to send data as form data? on server side you expect json, but from client side sending not as json.
From angular just send your object:
this.httpReq.post<WebResult>('http://localhost:8084/manage/add', nwUser).subscribe(response => {...});